# Extracting Code from two different Release labels in Clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I have a code base which is drawn from the below config spec in clearcase.

`element * CHECKEDOUT`
`element lost+found -none`
`element * ...\CRM_703_FP2_COE\LATEST`
`element * CRM_703_FP2_RELEASE -mkbranch CRM_703_FP2_COE`
`element * \main\0 -mkbranch CRM_703_FP2_COE`
But from the above code base i have around 400 files to be drawn from another label called `CRM_703_FP2_SPLIT` instead of `CRM_703_FP2_RELEASE`.

How can i achieve this? Can i add these 400+ files along with their full path and the required release label in the above config spec to achieve this? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an extra selection rule at the right place

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element lost+found -none
element * ...\CRM_703_FP2_COE\LATEST
element * CRM_703_FP2_SPLIT -mkbranch CRM_703_FP2_COE
element * CRM_703_FP2_RELEASE -mkbranch CRM_703_FP2_COE
element * \main\0 -mkbranch CRM_703_FP2_COE
```

The order is important (first rule that applies wins), and here versions labeled with `CRM_703_FP2_SPLIT` will be selected first, before versions labeled with `CRM_703_FP2_RELEASE`.